# submeter um form quando seleccionar uma opção select, sem fazer reload da página

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Preciso de submeter os dados de um form (estão hidden) quando selecionar a opção em select, isto com ajax sem reload da página.

Tenho o código seguinte, que funciona bem, mas não envia (POST) os dados do formulário que estão hidden:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action='#' name="dateForm">
<input type='hidden' name='cond_acao' class='form-control' value="edit_seccao_formando">
<input type="hidden" name="id_formando" value="<?=$linha_formandos[id_formando];?>">                             


<select name="id_seccoes" class="form-control" onchange="return postSelection">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">car</option>
    <option value="2">boat</option>
    <option value="3">plane</option>       
</select>

<div id='response_seccoes'></div>    

  <script>
    function postSelection(selectObject) {

        var id_seccoes = window.dateForm.id_seccoes.value = selectObject.options[selectObject.selectedIndex].value;
        var dataString = "id_seccoes=" + id_seccoes;

        $.ajax ({
        type:"post",
        url: "url.php",
        data:dataString,
        success: function (response) {

            $('#response_seccoes').html("ok").fadeIn(100).delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
            //$("#list").html(response);


        }
      });
        return false;
    };
 </script> 
</form>
```

É possível fazer o serialize ao invés de especificar as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer desta forma porém terá que alterar seu form colocando um id. e no seu select faça isso

`<select name="id_seccoes" class="form-control" onchange="document.forms['dateForm'].submit();">`

```
<form id='selector' class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action='#' name="dateForm">

$(document).ready(function(){

        var dataString = $( "#selector" ).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function( data )
            {
                alert( data );
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso que seja o select a despoletar o envio do form (submit) não queria que fosse um botão

Comment: editei a pergunta, tente desta forma acima e retorne aqui o  que acontece

Comment: Caro @Victor, obrigado pela sua ajuda. Perdoe-me mas sou fraco em javascript, com o código que me envia não consigo perceber como o select vai despoletar o submit do form.

Comment: vou alterar novamente @RuiBanha

Comment: consegiu @RuiBanha

Comment: Caro @Victor, desculpe só hoje consegui voltar a este assunto. O problema agora é que mal abro a página em causa aparece logo o alert (em popup). nem deixa correr o código. Porque será?

Comment: poste seu código novamente atualizado, e responda, agora o problema é este e o do select que não faz o submit ou só este ?

Comment: Desculpe só agora responder. Está resolvido. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RuiBanha marque a resposta que melhor te atendeu como melhor resposta, desta forma os usuários irão saber qual caminho tomar quando tiverem a mesma dúvida

Answer (score 2):

Você não está enviando os dados dos hidden. Utilize o [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) para enviar todos os dados do seu formulário.
Ex:

```
var dataString = $("form").serialize();
```

Comment: onde aparece "form" é o nome do form (form name)? tentei colocar o como me disse substituindo : var id_seccoes = window.dateForm.id_seccoes.value = selectObject.options[selectObject.selectedIndex].value;
        var dataString = "id_seccoes=" + id_seccoes;
mas os valores hidden não passaram

Comment: É um seletor JQuery, pode chamar pela tag, id, name etc. O serialize deveria funcionar sim, verifique se a função está sendo chamada corretamente. Se não estiver, tente alterar seu select para: <select name="id_seccoes" class="form-control" onchange="postSelection(this);">